# Asynk task not connecting when activity is resumed

Tags: android

I have an asynktask to connect to server. It works fine when the activity launches first time. when the activity is resumed after a pause , the asynk task wont execute . I have tried to call the `execute()` method in `onResume` as well but doesnt help.

```
public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TCPClient> {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run(SiteNumber);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
        //sc.showDialog(values[0]);
        if (pressedButton == DOOR) {
            if (values[0].equals(getString(R.string.Door_Opened))) {
                sentSucc();
                pressedButton = INACTVE;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I have defined the asynk task above my oncreate() `connectTask conn ;`

and in onCreate I call `conn.execute(");`

I have also tried to shifting this call to on resume();

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show where you are calling this `AsyncTask` in the main activity..

Comment: Are you creating new object of asynctask in onresume ? Post your activity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code In **onPause()** method Your activity
this code check asynctask status 
if Asynctask is running while Execute **onPause()** it will cancel that Asyctask Execution.
& in **OnResume()** method execute again Asyctask.

```
connectTask mTask;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

 if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
 {
    mTask.cancel(true);
  }  


}
```

**Edit:**

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onResume();

   mTask = new connectTask();
   mTask.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your `AsyncTask` within your *onResume()* method; because it will be called both times, when you start the activity at the first place, **and** when you actually *resume* it from a pause.

It should probably look like this :

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    // ...
    new connectTask ().execute();
}
```

Notice the way we are executing it anonymously, and we are using the `new` keyword with the constructor because we need to *create* an asynchronous task object in order to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You should call asynctask in `onResume()` method. because this method will be called after `onCreate()` when activity is created and as well as it is called when activity is resumed from another activity.

you should call your asynctask like following

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    new connectTask ().execute();
}
```

Hope it will help you.